# Exporting heat map / texture maps as SVG without referenced PNG files?

Tags: qgis, svg

When I create a map in QGIS and export it to SVG format, if there is a heat map or topographical texture map layer, those layers are exported as PNG files referenced by the SVG file.

Is there any way to avoid this?

This is annoying in its own right, but the greater problem is that I need my maps in EPS format. When I convert from SVG to EPS, the links between the SVG file and PNG layer are broken.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all raster layer are exported as image (PNG or JPG) there are no way around that as raster are basically image.

That being said you  may try to vectorise your raster.

Of course you will loose the continuous aspect of the raster but for data like heat map, DEM or other interpolated data converting to isoline then to polygon could produce acceptable result.

For texture or aerial photo vectorisation will likely loose to many detail but it may be tried

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: export the map from QGIS as a PDF, then open in Adobe Illustrator. From there it is possible to save as EPS, which results in a single, scalable file.